# Direction of plane waves composing the 2D Fourier transform

Tags: optics, waves, fourier-transform

A collegue told me that the 2D Fourier transform of a function $g(x,y)$  consists of plane waves travelling in different directions. I don't understand this connection. In which direction do the waves point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2D Fourier transform of the fct $g(x,y)$ is defined as
$$
G(f_x, f_y) \propto \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy\;
g(x,y) \, e^{i 2\pi(f_x x + f_y y)}
$$
where $\{f_x, f_y\}$ are the *spatial frequencies*. The exponentials are the **phasors** of plane waves. The direction of a plane wave is given by considering its phase (exponent)
$$
2\pi(f_x x + f_y y) =  \phi
$$
and solving for
$y$,
$$ 
y(x) =  \frac{1}{f_y} \left(
\frac{\phi}{2\pi} - f_x x
\right)
$$
[image]

where
\begin{align}
\theta &= \arctan(f_y/f_x) \\
L &= (f_x^2 + f_y^2)^{-1/2}
\end{align}

If we include the time evolution of a plane wave $e^{-i\omega t}$, we obtain the same equation, but the phase becomes time dependent $\phi(t) = -\omega t + \phi_0$.

The function $y(x)$ defines a direction along which the phase of the wave with spatial frequencies $(f_x, f_y)$ is constant. The propagation direction of the plane wave is perpendicular to this "constant phase" direction.

Comment: If your function $G$ does not depend on $t$ as you have written, or if the OP does not specify if the signal is time dependent, then where is the propagation?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: You are perfectly right. In optics we often omit the $e^{\pm i\omega t}$ term, but it is of course there.